# GarbageCollectorMXBean getCollectionCount :: Returns the total number of collections that have occurred

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jmx, mxbean

The doc for GarbageCollectorMXBean getCollectionCount says *Returns the total number of collections that have occurred*, is it from the start of the time of start of JVM?

From what I am seeing it looks like the number of GCs from the last poll on getCollectionCount. Where can I see a sample (maybe G1GC) implementation for GarbageCollectorMXBean?

Answer (score 1):

GarbageCollectorMXBean indeed returns total number of collections that have occurred since the start of the JVM.

What I was looking at was a wrapper over GarbageCollectorMXBean which used to explicitly maintain the lastValue & emit the difference.

Comment: To complete the answer, you should add the name of the wrapper, how you invoked it and how you managed to avoid it (and get the right numbers). IMHO such a wrapper can be useful, but it must in no case take the place of the original bean.

Comment: @Nisarg, I doubt it is from the start of the JVM because I am seeing values going up and down. Please share your findings.